# how to show same picked image in two Image Views in Xcode swift 3?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimageview, swift3, xcode8

I am unable to figure out how to use picked image and show it in two image view at the same time. Basically, I want user to click on button then select an image and after that the image is shown in two different image views( Using Swift 3 and Xcode 8 ).

```
@IBOutlet var imageview: UIImageView!
var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
@IBOutlet weak var effectView: UIVisualEffectView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    imageview.image = UIImage(named:"Selfie_4072_5194.jpg")
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imageview2.image = imageview.image
    imagePicker.delegate = self
}

@IBAction func camerabutton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func libraryBtn(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    imageview.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {})
}

@IBAction func Screenshot(_ sender: UIButton) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see where you are defining `imageview2` make sure you have added it as an outlet, and linked it in your storyboard.

```
@IBOutlet var imageview2: UIImageView!
```

It also looks like you are only setting the image for `imageview` try setting the image property of your `imageview2` too.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        imageview.image = image 
        imageview2.image = image
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {})
}
```

Comment: Thanks It Worked..!

Comment: Just got one problem.! that after running the app, it shows this error..! (fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) ).

Comment: And - This ERROR - PhotoLibraryServices (0x11aa69210). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.                                                                           In this line of code -   
        imageview2.image = UIImage(named:"Selfie_4072_5194.jpg")
        imageview.image = UIImage(named:"Selfie_4072_5194.jpg")
        imagePicker.delegate = self

Comment: That seems like a separate issue. maybe try searching for an answer to that one first, if you can't fix it or find an answer then ask another question.